# Freezes with Ubuntu 20.10 on Lenovo Thinkpad T14 AMD

Tags: thinkpad

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad T14 AMD that came with Windows 10 preinstalled. I didn't have any issues with this laptop when I was still using Windows. I took out the original SSD, put in a new Kingston A2000 1TB SSD and installed Ubuntu on that SSD.

A month or so ago I started to experience these weird out-of-nowhere freezes. The whole computer just freezes and the only thing I can do is move the mouse. I tried formatting the drive and installing Kubuntu 20.10 instead but the same thing keeps happening.

I was thinking that maybe this was a memory issue so I followed [this](https://linuxize.com/post/create-a-linux-swap-file/) guide and created a new swap file. Didn't help.

How can I debug this issue? How can I find what is causing this and how do I fix it?

**Hardware:**

- Lenovo Thinkpad T14 with AMD Ryzen 5 PRO 4650U and 16 GB of RAM
- Kingston A2000 1TB Nvme SSD

**Software:**

- Ubuntu 20.10
- Kubuntu 20.10

EDIT:

Just now I went to do other things and I noticed this going on on my display. What can be concluded from this?

[image: SSD error?]

Comment: Do you see anything in `/var/log/syslog` that might indicate the problem?

Comment: There's something like this `Jan 17 13:31:05 myusername-mycomputer kernel: [   23.824151] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7` but other than that, I can't really tell what is unwanted and what is not.

Answer (score 0):

uninstall last kernel update, or install a previous kernerl, surely there was an update in the kernel not ok for your system.
Also ubuntu 20.04 is more stable thant 20.10 if you prefer for lts and stability.

Comment: I would have gone with Ubuntu 20.04 except the kernel (5.4.something?) shipped with it is incompatible with Thinkpad T14. At least according to what I've read. I'll try installing a previous kernel.